# Pyspark / replacement based on a different column string

Tags: pyspark, replace

```
location = ['Seoul', 'Busan', 'Jeju']

df = df.withColumn('new_key_location', 
                    F.when(F.col('key_location').isin(location),
                    F.col('key_location')).otherwise(F.lit('Others')))
```

I created a new column called 'new_key_location', and except for locations Seoul, Busan, and Jeju, I named other locations as others.

However, I have a different column called 'location name'. There are also Seoul, Busan, and Jeju, but they were named as others in the new_key_location column.

How can I change 'others' in the new_key_location(newly created column) based on Seoul, Busan, and Jeju in the column 'location name.'

| key Location | location name | new_key_location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Others | Seoul | Others → Seoul |
| Others | Others | Others |
| Seoul | Seoul | Seoul |
| Others | Busan | Others → Busan |

Comment: What if key Location is `Seoul` but location name is `Others`?

Answer (score 1):

A simple case when (`when().otherwise()`) should work.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_location',
               func.when((func.col('new_key_location') == 'Others') & 
                         (func.col('location_name').isin(location)), func.col('location_name')).
               otherwise(func.col('new_key_location'))
               )
```

If `new_key_location` is "Others" but `location_name` is one of the locations in the list, it will update the value from "Others" to the one in `location_name` column.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me. My questions would be...what is the location name is not the same as the location = ['Seoul', 'Busan, 'Jeju']. I mean, what if their names are like Seoul_1, Seoul_namsan, seoul_gangnam......many other names in the 'location name'  column

Comment: @kkk__kkk then you'd have to use `like()` instead of `isin()`